# Do deceased persons need to have valid identification documents in order to legally enter France?

Tags: france

I read on https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/01/16/ramesses-ii-passport/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180930190829/https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/01/16/ramesses-ii-passport/)):

> However, in order for Ramesses’ mummy to be transported to France, the long-deceased pharaoh needed to have a valid passport. At that time, **French laws dictated that all persons, dead or alive, needed to have valid identification documents in order to legally enter France**.

Do deceased persons still need to have valid identification documents in order to legally enter France?

Comment: Well, otherwise it would be a very complicated legal situation if the person was to resucitate. Now seriously, I would expect *some* documentation will be needed to be attached to a coffin, at the very least a certificate of defunction.

Comment: Otherwise "playing dead" would be a way to enter a country without documentation.

Comment: From the article it sounds like French laws required more than a death certificate.

Comment: Transporting a corpose in or out of a country is often a quite complex issue with lots of red tape. IIRC, in France, there used to be a requirement (maybe there still is), that you needed special authorisation to even transport a corpse to a different _département_. I however doubt a _passport_ was actually needed, but there certainly was a need for quite a bit of paperwork.

Comment: Not if cremated.

Comment: [Ripley's](https://www.ripleys.com/weird-news/ramses-ii-the-mummy-who-had-a-passport/) says it was Egypt that required Rameses II to have a passport, not France. I can't find any authoritative sources either way.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer:**

yes, but it is a special passport (may possibly be) called
Mortuary (or Corpse) Passport (or only Pass)
(French: **laissez-passer mortuaire**, German: **Leichenpaß**)

The English expression used in the second treaty uses the French term (without **mortuaire**) .

---

**Full answer:**

There are two international conventions defining how a corpse should be transported between countries:

- 1932-02-10 Berlin
- 1973-10-26 Strassburg

The second convention is a simplified version of the first.

France has signed both, Egypt has signed only the first.

---

Further details can be found here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_on_the_Transfer_of_Corpses

The French / German text of the first treaty can be found here:
(the present wiki link to this is broken)

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/themen/internatrecht/-/240238